# Excel Shows "#########" when i try to write DateTime.Now.tostring() to one of the cell in Excel File

Tags: c#, excel

I have created a application in c# , it reads excel file and after checking some conditions, it select a row to be written in another Excel File.

Everything is working fine, but i need to end the file with the `DateTime.Now.ToString()`.

```
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
ExcelWorkSheet2.Cells[newFileRow, 1] = date;
```

When I see the file created, it shows "########" symbol instead of actual date. When I select that cell , it changes to correct date format.

What may be going wrong?

Comment: Maybe Excel hates to display a value in a field that's too narrow.

Comment: That's how Excel shows a cell whose width is too narrow for the selected display format, isn't it?

Comment: Yup, when i expand the cell, it does show me proper values. How do i do this programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expand the size of the cell to make it display properly.  This is most easily done by double clicking on the column header to make it expand to fit all data.

Comment: Yup, when i expand the cell, it does show me proper values. How do i do this programmatically? Giving the size to one of the column.

Comment: @user1209631 what do you mean by giving the size of one of the columns?

Comment: I mean providing width to the column?

Comment: ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)ExcelWorkSheet2.Cells[newFileRow, 1]).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = date.Length ;

Comment: @user1209631 try date.Length + N where N is some arbitary number that makes the column length large

Answer (score 3):

`#####` is typically shown by Excel when the value in the cell is too wide. What happens if you try to expand the column width a little bit?

Comment: Yup, when i expand the cell, it does show me proper values. How do i do this programmatically?

Comment: @KyleTrauberman: The _column_ is too narrow; the _value_ is too wide ;-)

Comment: @user1209631: It's been a while since I used VBA, but try the `ExcelWorkSheet2.Columns` property (not sure about whether you should write `Columns["A"]` or `Columns[1]`) - maybe each column has a `Width` property.

Comment: ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)ExcelWorkSheet2.Cells[newFileRow, 1]).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = date.Length ;

Answer (score 1):

Just try widening the column display a little.

Comment: Yup, when i expand the cell, it does show me proper values. How do i do this programmatically? Giving the size for one of the column?

Comment: ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)ExcelWorkSheet2.Cells[newFileRow, 1]).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = date.Length ;

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, the column isn't wide enough for your datetime value.

Without putting anything in the brackets, DateTime.Now.ToString() will return every detail of the current date.

You can cut this down by putting some speech marks in between the brackets, followed by some formatting information.

- dd for current date
- MM for current month
- yyyy for current year
- hh for current hour
- mm for current minute (notice the lowercase)
- ss for current second

So for example, if you just wanted the date without any time information, you would put the following which would return 2012-03-25:

```
var thisString = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Thanks

Comment: ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)ExcelWorkSheet2.Cells[newFileRow, 1]).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = date.Length ;

Comment: For future reference, you can just add a comment to your question and trust that we will see it, you don't need to add the same comment to every answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to shorten DateTime format and/or widen your cell a bit.
Please refer to [this information on DateTime formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

---

**More**:
`DateTime.Now.ToString()` usually produces long string, something like "3/25/2012 7:26:26 PM". If this is something you would like to display, then the only option for you is to make your cell/column wider.

Otherwise consider one of many formats that suit you well.
Example: `DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yy")`

Comment: ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)ExcelWorkSheet2.Cells[newFileRow, 1]).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = date.Length ;